# Redis - Get all Keys begining with

Tags: php, redis

I'm using TinyRedisClient with PHP for making calls to my redis database.

I'm looking to `GET` all keys that being with `Player:`

There are multiple keys such as `Player:17364633` `Player:12435435`
How would I get these by only knowing they begin with `Player:`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`KEYS`](http://redis.io/commands/keys) command to fetch a list of keys, and then [`GET`](http://redis.io/commands/get) each of them:

```
redis> KEYS Player:*
1) "Player:17364633"
2) "Player:12435435"
redis> GET Player:17364633
...
```

You can even do a little bit better by using [`MGET`](http://redis.io/commands/mget) to fetch all the values at once.

Comment: `KEYS`'s use is highly discouraged as it is O(n) and blocks - use `SCAN` instead.